# Set Background Picture to QTextEdit

Tags: python, background-image, qtextedit

How can I set a background picture to a QTextEdit Window in python?

So far my class looks like this:

```
class MoveText(QtGui.QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, example_text):
        super(MoveText, self).__init__()     
        self.setText(example_text) 
        self.initUI()



    def initUI(self):      
        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('MoveText')
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.show()
    ...
```

Can i set a picture by (www) url?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`setStyleSheet`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop):

```
def initUI(self):
    ...
    self.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(Qt-logo.png)")
    self.show()
```

According to simple experimentation, it seems like `setStyleSheet` with external url does not work.

You may need to download the image file yourself. For example:

```
import urllib

...

url = 'http://qt-project.org/images/qt13a/Qt-logo.png'
with open('background.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
self.setStyleSheet('background-image: url(background.png)')
```

Comment: I strongly dislike stylesheets in QT applications do you know how this can be done without style sheets? I know it's possible i just don't know how